# React 16.8 hooks - child component won't re-render after updating parent state

Tags: reactjs, state, mapbox-gl-js

I have a functional parent `Map` component with a few states, one of which is `layers`, the value of which is set initially from a config.

I then have a child `LayerControl` component which takes the layers state of the map as its props. The LayerControl component makes some changes and passes them back to the Map with `onLayerChange` which then subsequently calls the setState method of the layers (`setLayers`).

From what I understand, this should trigger a re-render of my LayerControl component, but it doesn't. What have I done wrong?

```
export default function Map(){

const [viewport, setViewport] = useState(mapConfig.viewport);
const [style, setStyle] = useState(mapConfig.mapStyle);
const [layers, setLayers] = useState(mapConfig.layers);

function updateLayers(layers){
    setLayers(layers); //why won't LayerControl re-render?
}

return(
    <MapGL
        zoom={[viewport.zoom]}
        containerStyle={{
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%"
        }}
        style={style}>
        <LayerControl
            onLayerChange={layers => updateLayers(layers)} 
            layers={layers}
        />
        <ZoomControl/>
        <ScaleControl/>
    </MapGL>
);

}
```

Comment: It won't re-render only if `layers` is the same object as previous state. How did you check that updateLayers was called? How did you check that the component wasn't re-rendered? Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: Maybe the issue resides or in LayerControl lifecycle/props comparison or in the layer object itself. Please provide a working snippet reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you creating a new layers Array in the LayerController or are you just adding/removing an item to the layers array? I assume `setLayers` only does a shallow reference check to see if `layers` changed, which will return false if you modified the array instead of re-creating it. Thus your component won't re-render.

For example

```
// In LayerController

// this mutates the array, but won't trigger a render
layers.push(/* some new layer */);
onLayerChange(layers);

// creates a new array, which should trigger a render
const newLayer = {/* your new layer */};
const newLayers = [...layers, newLayer];
onLayerChange(newLayers)
```

Comment: @Scarysize is there any way to specify how react checks if the element has been mutated?

Comment: I don't think so, AFAIK React only does a shallow comparison to check for mutation. You can of course implement shouldComponentUpdate in your components and do the check yourself: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate